# Accessing UK-specific QuickBooks reports

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

The UK version of QuickBooks Premier has a report called "UK Standard Balance Sheet" under "Reports > Company & Financial".

However, if I send a QBXML `GeneralSummaryReportQueryRq` request for a `BalanceSheetStandard` I get a different report simply called "Balance Sheet", which is ordered differently and has a couple of extra rows compared to the "UK Standard Balance Sheet".

This "Balance Sheet" report does not seem to be available from the "Reports" menu in QuickBooks, but it does get displayed if I set `<DisplayReport>true</DisplayReport>` in my QBXML request.

Is it possible to request the UK-specific report via QBXML or am I stuck with this other report that it's currently returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stuck with what is returned. Reports in the SDK are limited.  You might try BalanceSheetSummary and see what it returns.

Comment: Well `BalanceSheetSummary` returns a "Summary Balance Sheet" which again is ordered differently and has extra rows compared to the "UK Balance Sheet Summary" accessible through the QuickBooks menus. I was foolishly hoping that Intuit might have actually localised or extended the SDK for its international customers and that there would perhaps be some undocumented report type such as `UkBalanceSheetStandard`.